# CDI Bean not found from JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, cdi

I have a simple xhtml page with an el expression. But this expression won't get resolved and no error is thrown.

test.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<h:head>
    <title></title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    test
#{ffs.count}
</h:body>
</html>
```

Cdi Bean

```
@Named("ffs")
public class Test implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    EntityManager em;


    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public int getCount() {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.setName("Test");
        game.setType(Game.Type.PC);

        em.persist(game);
        em.flush();



        System.out.println(em.createQuery("Select g from Game g").getResultList().size());

        return em.createQuery("Select g from Game g").getResultList().size();

    }
}
```

rendered HTML output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Games/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
    <title></title></head><body>
    test

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let's do some trivial debugging yourself. Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*. What do you see? Do you see unparsed JSF source code or its generated HTML output? If you see unparsed source code, then JSF simply hasn't run at all, and that's quite different from the rather hard "JSF not working" statement. You're basically directly requesting the raw source code without invoking JSF's `FacesServlet`.

Comment: I called it through the `FacesServlet` URl. Therefor there where no unparsed el statements in the html output you can see above. But there is other output from the Bean either.

Comment: So, in contrary to what your question title suggests, JSF is working perfectly fine. I recommend to fix your title. Your problem is merely that the CDI bean cannot be found in EL scope. Did you enable CDI in your web application?

Comment: A beans.xml exsists. Shouldn't a not found Bean throw a `PropertyNotFoundException`?

Comment: A `PropertyNotFoundException` is -as its classname hints- only thrown when a property cannot be found, not when the base cannot be found. In your case, the base (the managed bean) does not exist anywhere in the EL scope. EL doesn't throw any exception when the base cannot be found (unless a property needs to be written). So, the `@Named` didn't do its job. So, CDI isn't properly installed/enabled. This is completely beyond JSF's scope. What if you try JSF's `@ManagedBean` instead? If that works, then you can definitely exclude JSF from being the cause.

Comment: Also, you cannot activate transactions the way you have them without an extension - e.g. Seam3 or DeltaSpike or even Apache CODI.  Are you using one of those in your code?

Comment: Can you check if CDI is launched by creating another bean and trying to @Inject in your ffs bean?

Also as @JohnAment point it CDI 1.0 doesn't support transaction. Your bean needs also to be an EJB to support `@TransactionAttribute`, so put a `@Stateless` under your `@Named` annotation

Comment: I have a very similar problem, el can't find the bean, but i can inject it just fine in a pagebean. Do i need to register some other el-reslovers for this?