# h:dataTable backing bean not called

Tags: jsp, jsf-2, datatable, cdi, websphere-8

In the JSP I am using an `h:dataTable` tag with value set to point to my getter method, which in turn returns a list of objects. The problem is that the `getListSignataireExceptions` is never called and the table is empty.

Please note that the `AdministrationBean` is well initialized, and if I put `#{administrationBean.listSignataireExceptions}` outside the table tag, I get the list of objects on the screen in non formatted way.

Same goes for `#{administrationBean.message}` - no message, the backing bean is not called.

JSP:

```
<div class="content">
    Administration des Exceptions signataires
    <h:dataTable id="table1" value="#{administrationBean.listSignataireExceptions}" var="item"
                 border="1">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Your Shopping Cart" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Item Description" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.idSociete}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Price" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.idAnnuaireSalarie}" />
        </h:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:outputText value="Total: #{administrationBean.message}" />
        </f:facet>
    </h:dataTable>
</div>
```

Backing bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class AdministrationBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Inject
    private AdministrationService service;

    public String getMessage(){
        return "test test";
    }

    public List<DtoSignataireException> getListSignataireExceptions(){
        return service.listSignatairesExceptions();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seriously using JSF2 on deprecated JSP view technology instead of its successor Facelets (XHTML)?

Comment: Not my choice of technology. Sometimes we have to deal with choice made by others

Comment: How does the generated HTML output look like? (open page in browser, rightclick, view source) Is the `<h:dataTable>` tag still there or is it properly parsed?

Comment: @BalusC, it is an empty html table, nothing special <tr><td></td></tr>, no hidden rows

Comment: OK, the `FacesServlet` is properly invoked and the `<h:xxx>` taglib is properly declared. So we can exclude that. Now, this is most likely caused by a configuration mistake. As JSP is very rarely used in JSF2, I haven't seen this problem before. You're basically the first one who describes this kind of problem. This can as of now only be answered if we know the server make/version, all libraries present in /WEB-INF/lib (incl versions), the root element declaration of web.xml and faces-config.xml (incl versions), so we could try to reproduce it ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to our Java EE container - WebSphere 8.
As mentioned in the question below, apparently CDI will only work for the default JSF implementation in WebSphere - MyFaces.

[CDI Bean not found from JSF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752938/cdi-bean-not-found-from-jsf-page)

Our application uses Mojarra and thus the container created by mojarra is not being picked up by OpenWebBeans (WAS CDI implementation).

The solution is to add a CDI enabler as described in the article below. This bridges the CDI through different containers. The only difference was that on my environment, I did not neet to add

```
<alternatives>
    <class>com.oracle.cdi_enabler.CdiConversation</class>
</alternatives>
```

https://weblogs.java.net/blog/mriem/archive/2013/12/10/jsf-tip-54-enable-cdi-when-bundling-jsf

Another solution is to declare the desired EL resolver in faces-config like so:

```
<application>
       <el-resolver>org.apache.webbeans.el.WebBeansELResolver</el-resolver>
  ..
<application>
```

Where you should replace WebBeansELResolver by the EL resolver of your implementation of CDI. In this case we were using OpenWeb Beans provided by the WAS container